# Deserialising JSON with HTML c#

Tags: c#, html, json, entity-framework, serialization

I am serialising an object in to JSON that includes a property that contains HTML

So my class looks as follows.

```
[Serializable]
public class ProductImportModel
{
  public string ProductName { get; set; }
  public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
}
```

So a record would look like

```
 ProductName = "Test Product";
 ShortDescription = "<p>TEST Product</p>";
```

I think store it to the database using entity framework

```
 var syncProduct = new SyncProduct();
 syncProduct.ProductId = Guid.NewGuid();
 syncProduct.SerializedProduct = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(importProduct);
```

If I look in the database it looks fine

```
  {"ProductName":"Test Product","ShortDescription":"<p>TEST Product</p>"}
```

I then want to retrieve the item using Entity Framework it remove the HTML tags

```
  var jsonProduct = context.SyncProducts.FirstOrDefault();

  jsonProduct.SerializedProduct 

  {"ProductName":"Test Product","ShortDescription":"pTEST Productp"}
```

I think it is some sort of encoding issue in Entity Framework.
How should I be retrieving it?

Comment: you should probably HtmlEncode it when you save to DB, then Decode it when you retrieve.

Comment: If SerializedProduct-column in DB is varchar there should not be any problem. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working now after changing the version of Json.net. It must have been a bug in the version.